# Android studio : What is the solution of imports error?

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I have a problem on android studio, I delete something that I don't know and after that the imports doesn't work. It show's to me - cannot resolve symbol `GoogleApiAvailabilit` and other error like that.

[image]

Comment: Post your gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addd this on your app gradle file and resync project, im currently using version 10.0.1 and its working fine in my project, if you need newest function you can try with version 12.0.1

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

Comment: @SohaibElMediouni glad it worked, please mark it as anwser

Answer (score 1):

For ConnectionResult and GoogleApiAvailability, add this line in your build.gradle(app)

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'